# HTML Forms: Radio buttons with text fields

Tags: html, forms

This seems like a simple problem, but how do I create a basic HTML form that has a series of radio button options, with the last one being a text field to fill in a custom response (i.e. "Other").

What I have now:

```
    Reason given for stop? <br>
    <input type="radio" name="reason" value="Fit Description">Fit Description<br>
    <input type="radio" name="reason" value="Suspicious Behavior">Suspicious Behavior<br>
    <input type="radio" name="reason" value="No Reason Given">No Reason Given<br>
    <input type="radio" name="reason" value="">Other<br>
```

Comment: You can't, a text field isn't a radio button. You need to have a radio button and a text field and the logic to connect them.

Comment: Can you use JavaScript and/or do you have jQuery?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Just add a text input field to it.

```html
Reason given for stop? <br>
<input type="radio" name="reason" value="Fit Description">Fit Description<br>
<input type="radio" name="reason" value="Suspicious Behavior">Suspicious Behavior<br>
<input type="radio" name="reason" value="No Reason Given">No Reason Given<br>
<input type="radio" name="reason" value="">Other <input type="text" name="other_reason" />
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/pgyA2/)**

Comment: Keep in mind, the name "other_reason" doesn't actually connect to the radio button with name of "reason." So, when submitting the form, the value of "Other" doesn't actually pass through unless you specifically ask for "other_reason."

Answer (score 5):

1. Create a text field, and set it to display:none;
2. Then with jQuery, detect when the 'Other' radio button is checked and show the textbox.
3. Then on your process script, do and if statement to see if the value of your radio button group is "" (nothing), and grab the post data of the textbox and do what you want with it.

Comment: OP hasn't mentioned using Java anywhere.

Comment: I didn't say java, I said jQuery, which is exactly what he needs for the problem he is explaining.

Answer (score 1):

There is a neat way to add text field alongside radio buttons without using functions or Javascript (jQuery).
Just add the radio btn (Other) and the text field next to it, on the top of your HTML form. Here is what i use:

Color:

```
<input type="radio" name="title[<?=$red?>][color]" value="" <?php if ($row['color'] != ' ') {echo 'checked';} ?> />Other <input type="text" name="title[<?=$red?>][color]" value="<?php echo $row['color'] ?>" style="width: 200px;" /> |

<input type="radio" name="title[<?=$red?>][color]" value="natural" <?php if ($row['color'] == 'natural') {echo 'checked';} ?> />natural|

<input type="radio" name="title[<?=$red?>][color]" value="stain" <?php if ($row['color'] == 'stain') {echo 'checked';} ?> />stain |

<input type="radio" name="title[<?=$red?>][color]" value="white" <?php if ($row['color'] == 'white') {echo 'checked';} ?> />white|
```

Basically you do not put value on the "Other" radio input, but on the text input so whatever you write in the text field will be send to db - its 1st field in the FORM. If nothing in the text field - the other checked radio input will be processed.

Hope this helps.

Comment: This way you will send a request `?myvariable=&myvariable=textvalue` which can really get interpreted as overriding the empty value with the one sent after. If you don't mind sending such a strange request, you could even use CSS `style="display: flex; flex-direction: column-reverse;"` on the container to make the "other" field appear last as OP has asked.

Answer (score 0):

Simply add a text field as you would normally but give it the same name attribute as the others, that way when accessing them you'll get one of them.

In JavaScript (which I assume you'll be using?) just access these elements and check the the textfield is empty, if it is get the radio buttons.

Answer (score 0):

Found a similar answer [here](https://ux.stackexchange.com/a/144369).

```js
function yesnoCheck() {
  if (document.getElementById('yesCheck').checked) {
    document.getElementById('ifYes').style.visibility = 'visible';
  } else document.getElementById('ifYes').style.visibility = 'hidden';

}
```

```html
<div>
  Yes
  <input type="radio" onclick="javascript:yesnoCheck();" name="yesno" id="yesCheck"> No
  <input type="radio" onclick="javascript:yesnoCheck();" name="yesno" id="noCheck" checked="checked">
  <br>
  <div id="ifYes" style="visibility:hidden">
    If yes, please explain: <input type='text' id='yes' name='yes'>
  </div>
</div>
```

> Note: You need to specifically target the `input type='text'` when you use this in a form