# How to customize google forms that have 'other-option-response' option and textbox (and get responses to google sheet)

Tags: html, google-sheets, customization, google-forms

So there are many websites out there that explain how to customize your own google form(linked to a google sheet) for your website, such as codepen and [this blog](https://blog.webjeda.com/google-form-customize/).

However, none that I have found so far explained how to deal with Google forms that have an 'other-option-response' option, like this: [my example with other gender](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qaFNs.png)

I have successfully worked out how to deal with google forms that do not include this on their forms (since their responses show up on their corresponding Google sheets). However, I am stumped when it comes to this feature, since I am able to submit the form, but no response shows up in the google sheet.

Here is the snippet of code that may be causing me trouble.

```
<label>Student's Gender:</label><br>
    <input name="entry.1921054985" type="radio" value="Male" required style="color: black;" onclick="document.getElementById('genderother').disabled=true;
                                        document.getElementById('genderother').value=''" />Male<br>
    <input name="entry.1921054985" type="radio" value="Female" style="color: black;" onclick="document.getElementById('genderother').disabled=true;
                                        document.getElementById('genderother').value=''" />Female<br>
    <input name="entry.1921054985" type="radio" value="__other_option__" style="color: black;" onclick="document.getElementById('genderother').disabled=false;
                                        document.getElementById('genderother').focus();" />Other:
    <input name="entry.1921054985.other_option_response" type="text" placeholder="Enter if applicable" style="color:black;" id="genderother" disabled/>
```

I am wondering if my way is the correct way of dealing with the 'other' response.

This is my first question on stackoverflow, so if I've done something wrong, or didn't do something, please tell me.

Answer (score 1):

Are you creating a Google Form or a published Web App making an HTML form?

For a Google Form, which the blog you referenced is working on, you would have something like:

```
var form = FormApp.openById('1234567890abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz');
 var item = form.addMultipleChoiceItem();
 item.setTitle('Do you prefer cats or dogs?')
     .setChoices([
         item.createChoice('Male'),
         item.createChoice('Female')
         item.createChoice('Prefer not to say')
      ])
     .showOtherOption(true);
```

Which is modified from the [Class MultipleChoiceItem documentation page](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms/multiple-choice-item#createchoicevalue)

It appears, however, that you are not using the Forms service but instead generating straight HTML.  If this is your intention, see this thread on [HTML Forms: Radio buttons with text fields](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12888612/html-forms-radio-buttons-with-text-fields)

Comment: I am using straight HTML. I know how to make HTML forms already. The form shows up. However, the response does not get recorded in the google sheet.

Comment: OK, the use of "google forms" in the post and addition of the google-forms tag suggested otherwise.  I removed the tag and added google-apps-script.

Comment: Also, did you look at the thread I linked in the last part of my response?  Since Google Apps Script is based on javascript that thread should apply to your needs.

Comment: I looked at it already. I think you misunderstand my question. I am not using the Google Apps Script (although would that be a better idea?). The radio button thread doesn't address how to utilize Google Forms.

So basically, I created a Google Form. That Google form is linked to Google SpreadSheet.

I do not want to use the Google Form directly, since I do not want users to leave my website. So instead, I am creating a form on my website, whose action attribute corresponds to the spreadsheet, and the input tags have names that correspond to those in the google forms.

Comment: and so the spreadsheet will record the responses that users enter into the form on my website.  This has worked before for me.

Only now, for the first time I am dealing with the 'other' response, and all of the sudden the spreadsheet no longer records the data.

Comment: Can you provide a link to a copy of the files involved?  If you are using a Google Form then the code will be inside the Form accessed via the Form editor. In that case you use code as in my post to create the radio button items and the Form should handle the rest.  If you are creating a complete form using straight HTML you are better served with script embedded in the spreadsheet, published as a Web App, coding the script to save to the spreadsheet. Last, you can create code and use the API to save the form data to a spreadsheet. This parallels the Web App option embedded in the spreadsheet.

Comment: [This is the Google Form.](https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLSfGwmW9lXIpsBJODXjK8C7CnJVDLd91S4Fi9l1Nbf5KmVFbbg/viewform)

[This is the html file with the form](https://github.com/songdavid98/IvyPrepWebsite/blob/master/apply.html)

I'm afraid that I don't really understand your last two sentences about the Web App. Could you further explain that?

Comment: How were the items in your Form created? Is there additional code outside the HTML you provided? I'm trying to recreate. Your HTML [produces this page](https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbx-gfFOlADJsCGc_4LDDRO4m-UH16ab0oPxywrbLQWk/dev). This was generated by script this [Form document](https://docs.google.com/forms/d/1FpgcMpj4Bvb-AFrTrYrhrxMziwo97aMPNOeCV1-zKx8/edit) Open the Script editor in the drop down menu. The doGet() function has the Web App show the HTML form which is an HTML file inside the script. I used the Publish->Deploy as web app menu item to publish the code to run it.

Comment: The items in the form were created purely using HTML. The names of the input tags were copied and pasted from the source code of the Google Form that I created (this is from following the instructions in the blog above). Any additional code will be in the github repository. Also, I cannot access the first link that you gave ('your HTML produces this page').

Comment: My apologies, I thought I set that to allow for access.  I see what you are trying now.  Did you copy the hidden names from the end of the form?  Try a second form and simplify your Google Form for an initial starting point to only have this 1 item and make sure you get it working.  There are  4 hidden items in the original Google Form.  From the blog you should use the appropriate name in for Option and Select, you may need the same for Radio items.

Comment: The link works now: it seems to be exactly what I intended. I did not copy the hidden names at the end of the form. Are you referring to the hidden input tags? You seem to be on to something. I checked the other forms that I have dealt with, and none of the other ones seem to have the 4 hidden inputs. I've done this with previous Google Forms, and I have been successful. This is the only time I've encountered a problem

Comment: Yes, the hidden input tags. The blog has a paragraph referring to them for select items and suggest they may be needed for other items as well.  Reducing a trial down to just radio buttons and following the complete steps should help with that.  Note that this is an old method when many abandoned after Google made some changes and the forms using this method stopped working.  Probably because of these hidden tags, etc.  I use the Web App method and actually bind the code to the receiving spreadsheet. That allows me to place the data in different tabs similar to database tables.

Comment: I see. Thank you. Are there any links and tutorials that you would recommend that would teach me how to use the Web App method?

Comment: See [this Google Apps Scripting post](http://googleappscripting.com/doget-dopost-tutorial-examples/) as well as the following pages:  [Web Apps](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/web),  [HTML Service: Create & Serve HTML](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/),  [HTML Service: Templated HTML](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/templates),  [HTML Service: Best Practices](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/best-practices) and [Troubleshooting](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/support/troubleshooting) page.